# What device could be used to clamp a 0-10 VDC output from a pot to a lower VDC

Tags: converter, controller, clamp

We have an outdated machine where software along with most everything else, is obsolete. I am looking for a way, to take the 0-10 VDC output from a potentiometer, which is used as a reference for speed control, and clamp the max 10 VDC to say 6 VDC. It was thought about building our own clamper type circuit, but figured there has to be some sort of converter/controller that could do the same thing. I was looking at possibly a buck converter, however I am unsure as to how this would perform do the input frequency being constant as well as variable.

Comment: Are you wanting to scale 0-10 V down to 0-6, or are you wanting simply to limit the maximum to 6? The latter case could be as simple as adding a Zener diode.

Comment: Would you like it scaled down to 0-6 V (straight line) or clamped to 6 V max (ramp followed by shelf)?

Comment: why wouldn't a voltage divider work? I know it's obvious but I'm trying to understand the problem

Comment: @JYelton Great minds think alike... Was typing as you posed.

Comment: The thought is to use the reference voltage from the pot from 1-(lets call it 6 or 7vdc) **we are not sure exactly what our max speed is going to lie just yet, and not allow it to go any higher. So, we do not want to scale the input, rather clamp to a specific voltage.

Answer (score 5):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ZrHf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The output voltage range can be restricted by the addition of a series fixed resistor to form a potential divider.*

Ideally R3 should be 660 Ω if the original pot is 1 kΩ. 680 Ω is the closest standard value. Scale up to match the potentiometer.

Figure 1c shows how to make the speed limit adjustable. Connect the anti-clockwise end of the pot to the wiper and it will adjust the speed limit from 50% to 100% with clockwise rotation. (The series resistance of the pot will decrease with clockwise rotation.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple clamping circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKuy97.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output voltage will be clamped to Vclamp  for 1.5 < Vclamp < 10V.